# Firebase serverTimeOffset and Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP differences

Tags: time, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

## Context

- I have multiple servers listening to a specific collection (/items). Each of them use NTS for time calibration and the "`.info/serverTimeOffset`" to measure the expected time difference with Firebase. It is consistently around 20ms.
- I have many clients pushing items to the collection with the specific field:

  {
    ... 
    created: Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  }

## What is expected:

- When the server receives the item from Firebase and subtracts the `item.created` with the Firebase expected time (`Date.now() + offset`), this value should be **positive** and probably around 10ms (time for the item to be sent from Firebase to the server).

## What is happening:

- When the server receives the items, the `item.created` field is **superior** to the Firebase expected time. Like it was created in the future. Usually the difference is around -5ms

## Question:

- What is the Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP set to ? and how is it related to the ".info/serverTimeOffset" ?
- The 27th September 2016 at 1am UTC, that difference jumped from -5ms to around -5000ms like a kind of re-calibration happened (it lasted until I reset the `.info/serverTimeOffset`) Did someone experienced something similar?

Comment: Does this question belong to SO or ServerFault or WebApp?

Comment: @qarma the question seems on-topic to me, but I understand why you're asking. Crystalin: please include the [minimum code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your expectation is definitely wrong: the initial estimate for the timestamp can be both too early and too late.